# @OrderBy not working properly in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

How does `@OrderBy` work?

It is not working here in the following code:

**Employee.java**

```
package com.semanticbits.pojo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany; 
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;

@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private int employeeId;
private String name;
private double salary;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")
@OrderBy("city DESC")
private List<Address> address;






//setters and getters
public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public List<Address> getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
    this.address = address;
}

  }
```

**Address.java**

```
package com.semanticbits.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Address {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int addressId;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private int zipCode;

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public int getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
 }

}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="orderbyannotationdemo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider></provider>

        <class>com.semanticbits.pojo.Employee</class>
        <class>com.semanticbits.pojo.Address</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoaib"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

This is the test class......check out the city name and it is not storing address values in order in descending order in the ADDRESS table

**JPAOrderByAnnotationTest**

```
 package com.semanticbits.test;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
 import javax.persistence.Persistence;


 import com.semanticbits.pojo.Address;
 import com.semanticbits.pojo.Employee;

 public class JPAOrderByAnnotationTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory factory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("orderbyannotationdemo");
    EntityManager manager=factory.createEntityManager();

    Employee employee=new Employee();
    employee.setName("Shoaib");
    employee.setSalary(1452365);

    Address addressOffice=new Address();
    addressOffice.setCity("Hyderabad");
    addressOffice.setStreet("Gachibowli");
    addressOffice.setState("AP");
    addressOffice.setZipCode(500016);

    Address addressHome=new Address();
    addressHome.setCity("Noida");
    addressHome.setStreet("Chandai Chowk");
    addressHome.setState("UP");
    addressHome.setZipCode(415608);

    Address addressCollege=new Address();
    addressCollege.setCity("Antartica");
    addressCollege.setState("Canada");
    addressCollege.setStreet("New York");
    addressCollege.setZipCode(402103);

    List<Address> addresses=new ArrayList<Address>();
    addresses.add(addressHome);
    addresses.add(addressOffice);
    addresses.add(addressCollege);

    employee.setAddress(addresses);

    manager.getTransaction().begin();

        manager.persist(employee);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();

    manager.close();




}
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put the annotation to the getter and not to the field?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `@Orderby` annotation actually does. According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html):

> Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued
>   association or element collection at the point when the association or
>   collection is **retrieved**.

[emphasis added] The annotation does not dictate insertion order. Continuing with your example, if you were to fetch an `Employee`:

```
Employee employee = manager.find(Employee.class, employeeId);
List<Address> addresses = employee.getAddress();
```

Then `addresses` would be sorted by `city` in descending order.

Answer (score -2):

according to the spec you would have to use:

```
@OrderBy("address.city DESC")
```

Comment: This is incorrect...check the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) again. Particularly Example #3.

Comment: The dot (".") notation is used to refer to an attribute within an embedded attribute. The value of each identifier used with the dot notation is the name of the respective embedded field or property.