# JPA/JPQL - Many-to-many relation - OrderBy doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, jpql

I have a User and a Role class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OrderBy("name")
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private SortedSet<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
}
```

This results in three database tables:

```
User
+ id

Role
+ id
+ name

User_Role
+ users_id
+ roles_id
```

Now I want to query users and sort them by the role name via JPQL:

```
SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.roles ASC
```

My database is MariaDB. Unfortunately, Hibernate generates the following native and invalid query:

```
select us0_.id as id2_2_ from User us0_ cross join User_Role roles1_, Role role2_ where us0_.id=roles1_.users_id and roles1_.roles_id=role2_.id order by . ASC
```

**order by . ASC** is obviously not a valid query part. What am I doing wrong? I also tried @OrderColumn and @org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: is it anyway ok to have both `@OrderBy` and order in JPQL as you have for `roles`? I guess it is not ok to sort by `Collection`. For @OrderBy see [@OrderBy not working properly in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965877/orderby-not-working-properly-in-jpa)

Comment: You are ORDERing User records, so obviously cannot order by some Set field!!

Comment: First you need to clarify what you want to order by. As mentioned above, ordering by a set doesn't make any sense on it own. Do you want to sort on it's size, it's minimum id, avg name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation OrderBy doesn't have any effect on JPQL. If you want to query users and sort them by the role name via JPQL, you can use join in JPQL:

```
SELECT u FROM User u join u.roles r ORDER BY r.name ASC
```