# JPA why OrderBy is applied to Set

Tags: jpa, sql-order-by

JPA why OrderBy is applied to Set?

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html

```
@Entity 
public class Person {
     ...
   @ElementCollection
   @OrderBy("zipcode.zip, zipcode.plusFour")
   public Set<Address> getResidences() {...};
   ...
}
```

The Set is supposed to be not ordered. Is it meaningful to annotate @OrderBy
on attributes with Set type?

Comment: *Set is supposed to be not ordered*: that depends on the Set implementation. A LinkedHashSet has a well-defined order, for example. Either it's a documentation error, or, more reasonably, the JPA provider must make sure to use an ordered set implementation in that case.

Comment: Set is a collection that doesn't allow duplicates. It has no restrictions on ordering, so OrderBy is just as valid on a Set as it is on List or Collection.

Comment: "It has no restrictions on ordering" ? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer marked as checked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965877/orderby-not-working-properly-in-jpa?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question can answer also yours.
As mentioned there, the annotation "Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued association or element collection **at the point when the association or collection is retrieved**."

From what I understand, the annotation is not necessarily connected with the order that the elements are inserted on the Collection type that we use in the entity class.